# Access Values in Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript

I've seen a lot of different ways to access values in an array of objects. One being `arr.forEach(Function)` in which the function is simply a `for...in`

But im curious, how come two `for...in` functions does not work, for example:

`[{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }]`

(Taken from freeCodeCamp).

This works:

```
function myFunction (item, index) {

  for( var key in item ) {
    console.log(item[key])
  }
}
```

`arr.forEach(myFunction` ( prints all the values fine)

but how come this does not work:

```
for(key in arr)
{
   for(value in key)
   {
    console.log(key[value];
   }
}
```

I would think this would work, since we can do arr[key] (and print out the objects in the outer loop, but im not able to access the values this way)

edit:

Sidenote: is it possible for me to print out each sub key/value pair: IE for example on Array index 0 to print out `"first: "Romeo"` and then `"last: "Montague"`

Comment: `for/in` should not be used on arrays as they will iterate all properties of the object, including inherited ones. `for/in` should be exclusively used on objects.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea for more discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but how come this does not work:

Because `key` in that case would be a `string`, not an element of the array.

You shouldn't use `for..in` to iterate over arrays: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Newer versions of JavaScript (ECMAScript) provide the ability to use `for..of` loops, which are perfect for iterating over arrays:

```
for (var item of arr) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: Ah, well...is there a way for me to grab a subsection object in the array, for example if I wanted to print out the first key/value pair in the arr index 1:

Like printing out: `first: "Romeo"` and then `last: "Montague"`

Comment: You could just use a regular `for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)` and then `if(i > limit) break`. Or use the `for..of` loop and keep a separate iteration count variable.

Comment: @msmith1114 Yeah, just get the item at index 1 and print its values: `var idx1 = arr[1]; if (idx1) { for (var key in idx1) { console.log(key, ':', idx1[key]); } }`

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because `key` in the second `for ... in` is dynamic, same reason you can't do `item.key` in the first example

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the indices of the array and then over the keys of an item of the array.

```js
var array = [{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }],
    key, index;

for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
   for(key in array[index]) {
      console.log(array[index][key]);
   }
}
```